# Can you step into specific properties in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, attributes

I know that you can either step into every property or not step into every property, but I would really like to be able to step into a specific property, and not the rest. Is this possible? (I also know I can use keyboard commands, but I'm asking if there's a more permanent solution.) I have a lot of properties and my setters do important things, so it's silly to step over them, but most of my getters are pointless. I'm looking for something like:

```
public string ImportantProperty
{
    get { return _importantProperty; }
    [DebuggerStepThrough(false)]
    set
    {
        if (this.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Important Property cannot be changed unless This is closed.");
        if (ImportantProperty == value)
            return;
        _importantProperty = value;
        OnImportantPropertyChanged(new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't find anything that will act like `[DebuggerStepThrough(false)]` and I must resort to [turning off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388.aspx) property step-over and putting `[DebuggerStepThrough]` *everywhere* I don't want to step-through.

Comment: 1. Interesting question. I would probably ask John Robbins for a solution.
2. Instead of new EventArgs() it is better to use EventArgs.Empty.

Comment: Also, check if anyone subscribes for the event before raising it, otherwise an exception will be thrown. That is: if(OnImportantPropertyChanged != null) OnImportantPropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put breakpoints in properties' setters of interest only and press F5 to run till the next breakpoint?

Why don't you step-over unimportant properties -at setting them- by pressing shift+F11?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has information published for how to do this in Visual Studio 2010 and 2008. These techniques work fine in Visual Studio 2012.

[How to: Step Into Properties and Operators in Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667388(v=vs.100).aspx)

Read through all of the steps if you want, or just edit the **Tools** > **Options** using the screen capture below (check or uncheck that one item):

[image: screenshot]

### Where is this useful?

If you uncheck the item **Step over properties and operators (Managed only)**, then <kbd>F11</kbd> will step into a property or method. <kbd>F10</kbd> will step over it.